# Elastic Search Initial Configuration and Setup

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We're using the following Technologies: AWS RDS, Java and EC-2 Instances Running.

We're planning to implement Elastic Search to our App,

Please help us with Initial Setup Plan for below,

1. Complete DB tables indexing (Bulk Ingestion)
2. Regular indexing in Elastic Search on the basis of regular table data changes

How to achieve the above 2 points? Any Tools & Suggestions? Overall Flow?

Kindly advise, Thanks.

I'm a novice, need advise.

Comment: Hellow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask